# Escaping many layers of cascaded single and double quotes in osx bash

Tags: bash, escaping, line-breaks, double-quotes, single-quotes

I use a Mac (osx sierra) and I have been learning how to use the bash. I am trying new stuff as I go along to grasp some concepts. This time I was experimenting with functions and aliases. But then I couldn't wrap my head around this problem:

I first echoed this function into the .profile to insert new aliases and functions easily into the .profile file.

```
function editprofile(){
echo "$@" >> ~/.profile
}
```

This function worked very well for some alias insertions. But after I tried to insert an alias for the script (the script below) that makes my mac sleep, I realized that the function creates some diffuculties with the cascading single and double quotes. I believe this will be the case for most scripts that uses lots of layers of single and double quotes.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep' && exit
```

The code below is me trying to use my function to insert the code above as an alias into the .profile.

```
editprofile 'alias _sleep=' "'" 'osascript -e' "'" 'tell application "Finder" to sleep' "'" '&& exit' "'"
```

The problem is that when the second script is echoed into the .profile file, I should still keep some escape characters, otherwise the code is interpretted by the bash incorrectly. I think this would also be the case with may other scripts that have this many layers of quotes, so I though I should ask if there is any way around.

P.S.
On a related note, it seems like when I type this:

```
function editprofile(){echo "$@" >> ~/.profile}
```

instead of this:

```
function editprofile(){
echo "$@" >> ~/.profile
}
```

into the .profile file, the script doesn't work. Is it because of the line breaks?

Comment: Alias? Why would you use an alias? If you use a function, you can ask the shell to emit it on your behalf in correctly-quoted form.

Comment: Well, I'm new at this. Could you explain that a little bit more in depth?

Comment: BTW, the `function` keyword prevents your code from being POSIX-compliant, but has no benefit over the standards-defined function declaration syntax. Consider avoiding it.

Comment: I just would like to make the mac sleep by just typing _sleep or slp or something like that instead of all that osascript stuff. At least that was my purpose at the beginning.

Comment: Why are you asking for something so complicated as doing automated escaping if that's all you want?

Comment: Just edit your `.profile` directly; there's no need to add an additional layer of complexity by having a function edit the file for your.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a function, as opposed to an alias:

```
_sleep() { osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep' && exit; }
```

...you can emit its text with `declare -f`. Thus:

```
declare -f _sleep >>~/.profile
```

...or, to use your existing `editprofile` function:

```
editprofile "$(declare -f _sleep)"
```

The easiest approach is just that: Define the function in your local shell, then have the shell itself do the work of emitting it -- and **quote that emitted content** so it doesn't get field-split into individual arguments (and then have those arguments individually evaluated as globs).

---

If you *don't* want to go that route, there are approaches available; they're just varying degrees of unpleasant.

```
printf -v cmd_var '%q ' osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep'
```

...will put correctly-quoted contents into `"$cmd_var"`. You could then:

```
printf -v sleep_def '_sleep() { %s && exit; }' "$cmd_var"
```

...which will give you a function declaration in `sleep_dev` that can be `eval`ed to execute it locally, or appended to your `.profile`, &c.

```
editprofile "$sleep_def"
```

...will behave appropriately in that context.